# How can I use openscap to do an offline OVAL scan of a Cisco router?

Tags: cisco, oval, cve, openscap

[This doc](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/oval_scty_automation.html#scanning) describes a process of scanning a router's "show tech" file with a joval utility.

I downloaded joval's trial, but didn't see that utility.

Can openscap do offline OVAL scans of Cisco routers?

I want the routers to generate some file (show tech or whatever) that can be validated by an OVAL scanner. The routers will TFTP that file to some location were an OVAL scanner will validate them.

Can openscap or some other product do this? I want offline scans of files not online polling or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSCAP needs to be installed on the system to able to scan it.
I'm not familiar with architecture or OS used in Cisco routers, but if you can install or compile openscap, it may be able to do a scan.

You can check compiling instructions for OpenSCAP here: https://github.com/OpenSCAP/openscap#compilation